# Unable to implement (react-native-document-picker)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, document, picker

I have followed all process in given document but still I get below error in both platform:

**Following link** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker

> console.error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_reactNativeDocumentPicker.DocumentPicker.show')" error
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:57115:29 attachment
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:101355:24 onPress
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:101392:36
>   touchableHandlePress
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:42176:47
>   _performSideEffectsForTransition index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15001:36
>   _receiveSignal index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:14930:46
>   touchableHandleResponderRelease
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:14815:26
>   invokeGuardedCallback
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15268:21
>   invokeGuardedCallback
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15337:40
>   invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15340:54
>   executeDispatch
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15498:64
>   executeDispatchesInOrder
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15518:26
>   executeDispatchesAndRelease
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15613:35
>   executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15626:43
>   forEachAccumulated
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15603:22
>   runEventsInBatch
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15714:29
>   runExtractedEventsInBatch
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:15723:25 
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:16723:36
>   batchedUpdates$1
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25008:20
>   batchedUpdates
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:16663:33
>   _receiveRootNodeIDEvent index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:16722:23
>   receiveTouches
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:16752:34
>   __callFunction index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2593:49 
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2370:31 __guard
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2546:15
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>   index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2369:21

**Code Used :**

```
import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from 'react-native-document-picker';

// iPhone/Android
attachment = () => {
        DocumentPicker.show({
            filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.allFiles()],
        }, (error, res) => {
            this.setState({ ImageLoad: true })
            console.log(res, 'res data');
            if (res && res.uri) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('messagefile', { name: res.fileName, uri: res.uri, type: res.type });
                console.log("form data : ", formData);
                console.log("API Uplod file : ", LOCAL_URL + '/api/uploadChatFiles')
                fetch(LOCAL_URL + '/api/uploadChatFiles', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                    body: formData,
                }).then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((responseJson) => {
                        this.setState({ ImageLoad: false });
                        console.log('responseJson file name: ', JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.fieldname));
                        console.log('responseJson : ', JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                        if (responseJson.code === 200) {
                            this.setState({ visibleModal: null })
                        }

                        let message = {
                            text: responseJson.data.originalname,
                            from: this.props.senderId,
                            to: this.props.reciverId,
                            isFile: "1"
                        }

                        let messageJson = {
                            message: message,
                            to: this.props.reciverId,
                        }
                        this.socket.emit('message', messageJson);
                        this._storeMessages(message);

                    })
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code.

Comment: check it... @SathvikNasani

Comment: i think the package is not installed properly can you uninstall it and install it and do manual linking NOT with react-native link